# Join three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been working on the mimic II database and I don't understand how to use joins between 3 tables.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT p.hospital_expire_flg,
       COUNT (*)
FROM poe_med m, poe_order o, d_patients p
WHERE m.poe_id=o.poe_id
AND o.subject_id=p.subject_id
AND drug_name_generic = 'Metoprolol'
GROUP BY p.hospital_expire_flg
```

I'm guessing I have to use JOIN AS for the 3 tables. But not sure how to.

Comment: Please learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Fixed some formatting, removed tag from title and removed unnecessary tags

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT p.hospital_expire_flg
FROM poe_med `m`
INNER JOIN poe_order `o`
ON m.poe_id = o.poe_id
INNER JOIN d_patients p
ON o.subject_id = p.subject_id
WHERE drug_name_generic = 'Metroprolol';
```